# CRM Plugin locks entity

Tags: plugins, locking, dynamics-crm-2011

I've a problem by programing a webapplication for CRM Dynamics 2011. A self-made CRM-Plugin is triggered by deleting a certain customer entity. But the webapplication should make it possible to delete exactly that customer-entity. As soon as the webapplication tries to delete this entity, the plugin is triggered and locks the entity and the webapplication runs in an error. The Plugin has the state "pre operation", which is really necessary for the logic within the Plugin, so it's not possible to use the asynchronous processing.
Is there any way to avoid this problem?

Comment: Can you delete the entity from the CRM interface or does this problem only occur with the custom web application you're programming?

Comment: It only appears with the web application. I can delete the entity from the CRM Interface.

Comment: I doubt it is the plugin if it is working from the UI. I assume your WebApp is making a `IOrganizationService.Delete` call to the entity. Have you tried making that call from LINQPad to see if you can recreate the bug.

Comment: How you call deleting of that record from your app?
Maybe you can use async/await in your app to wait while your plugin will work with that record and only after that proceed with your code?